# Shortening repeating functions

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make the sliders output the values depending on the which button has been clicked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<div id="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="function1()" value="1">
<input type="button" onclick="function2()" value="2">
<input type="button" onclick="function3()" value="3">

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

function function1() {
 var a = 'test1'
    console.log('test: ' + a +' '+ slider.value);
}

function function2() {
 var a = 'test2'
    console.log('test: ' + a +' '+ slider.value);
}

function function3() {
 var a = 'test3'
    console.log('test: ' + a +' '+ slider.value);
}

</script>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see for each of the buttons, the functions are being repeated and only the variable 'a' is being changed. I was wondering if there was a way to make this code more efficient, in other words shorter.

Please let me know if you have any solutions for this.
Thanks.

Comment: so pass it in as an argument....

Comment: if you know what the value of `a` will be in the particular function can't you just pass the value if variable in the function

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @epascarello can you show an example please?

Comment: @Piterden there is no problem, the code works but, i want to make the repeated functions more efficient

Comment: `onclick="functionName('foo')"` and `functionName (a) {}`

Comment: since you are not having trouble, the code review forum is a better place to ask for a review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could inspect the element that triggered the event to get it's associated value like this and to be consistant with yoru slider you can bind to all inputs with a special class like this:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');

output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  var button = buttons[i];
  button.onclick = function() {
    var a = 'test'+this.value;
    console.log('test: ' + a +' '+ slider.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
<input type="button" class="button" value="1">
<input type="button" class="button" value="2">
<input type="button" class="button" value="3">
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the `updateValue` function will always be run in the context of the DOM element anyway, so you don't need to pass `this` as an argument because the value of `this` inside the `updateValue` function will be the same as the argument you are passing.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I can omit the `this` argument from the `onclick="updateValue(this)"` and access the value from calling `this.value` inside the `updateValue()` function? I tried, but `this` does not have a `value` property (unless it's inside some deeper property that I'm not familiar with)

Comment: Unless there is some quirk in the StackOverflow code snippet editor that messes with event binding

Comment: I agree with @JasonSperske, using `this` in stack snippet gives you the `[object window]` not the element, in this context to be precise.

Comment: @JasonSperske - my bad - when using the DOM API to assign an `onclick` handler (e.g. `myButton.onclick = someFuncReference`) then `someFuncReference` is executed in the context of `myButton` - but not when you declare it in HTML (`<button onclick="someFuncReference()"></button>`).

Comment: Using the DOM API would be the cleanest approach, it leaves the door open to replacing vanilla JavaScript with a more capable framework later on and limited the behavior/data/presentation binding

Comment: Updated with cleaner event binding approach, thanks for the tip @Adam :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to define the same variable again and again and multiple functions to perform the same task.

Use:

```
<input type="button" onclick="some_function('test1')" value="1">
<input type="button" onclick="some_function('test2')" value="2">
<input type="button" onclick="some_function('test3')" value="3">
```

to use the same function.

```
function some_function(a) {
    console.log('test: ' + a +' '+ slider.value);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<div id="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="function_name('test1')" value="1">
<input type="button" onclick="function_name('test2')" value="2">
<input type="button" onclick="function_name('test3')" value="3">

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

function function_name(a) {
    console.log('test: ' + a +' '+ slider.value);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Never do so, @user37 it's the bad practice!

Comment: @Piterden - if you're going to make that comment then you should also propose the alternative. In the context of the question, this is a perfectly good answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let slider = document.getElementById('myRange');
let output = document.getElementById('output');

let setOutputHTML = function (value) {
  output.innerHTML = value;
};

let setSliderValue = function (e) {
  slider.value = e.currentTarget.value;
  slider.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
};

slider.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  setOutputHTML(e.currentTarget.value);
});

setOutputHTML(slider.value);

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[type="button"]'))
  .forEach(function (input) {
    input.addEventListener('click', setSliderValue);
  });
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="output"></span></p>
</div>

<input type="button" value="25" name="field_slug" />
<input type="button" value="50" name="field_dlug" />
<input type="button" value="75" name="field_flug" />
```

Comment: I like that `Array.from().forEach()` approach, very clean

Answer (score -1):

Basically, just pass `this` to the function and since the value indicated on the button is what is different for each button, we just concatenate that to 'test' and pass that to the string.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <body>
    <div id="slidecontainer">
      <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
      <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="setSliderValue(this)" value="1">
    <input type="button" onclick="setSliderValue(this)" value="2">
    <input type="button" onclick="setSliderValue(this)" value="3">
    
    <script>
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;
    
    slider.oninput = function() {
      output.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
    
    function setSliderValue(button) {
        var value = button.value
     var testType = 'test' + value;
        console.log('test: ' + testType +' '+ slider.value);
    }
    
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```